# Bosun: Hbase org.hbase.async.RemoteException

Tags: hbase, opentsdb, bosun, scollector

After running bosun with about 500 scollectors, I see various issues in the logs. This on is from the opentsdb stdout log.

```
org.hbase.async.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionServerAbortedException: Server localhost,39157,1475044082464 aborting
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.checkOpen(RSRpcServices.java:980)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.get(RSRpcServices.java:1895)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.makeException(RegionClient.java:1738) [asynchbase-1.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decodeException(RegionClient.java:1756) [asynchbase-1.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:1468) [asynchbase-1.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.decode(RegionClient.java:88) [asynchbase-1.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.hbase.async.RegionClient.handleUpstream(RegionClient.java:1206) [asynchbase-1.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.messageReceived(SimpleChannelHandler.java:142) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateAwareChannelHandler.handleUpstream(IdleStateAwareChannelHandler.java:36) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.messageReceived(IdleStateHandler.java:294) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.hbase.async.HBaseClient$RegionClientPipeline.sendUpstream(HBaseClient.java:3108) [asynchbase-1.7.1.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [netty-3.9.4.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read
```

I also see a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error sometimes.

One thing I changed recently is to use my own zk cluster, and have set the `tsd.storage.hbase.zk_quorum=ip1,ip2,ip3` in opentsdb.conf.

Any configs that can be tuned to get this working for about 1200 scollector instances, using the containerized bosun.
This is for a PoC, and I are not looking to configure and scale the modules separately as of now.

Comment: We're using scollector but not bosun. One thing to watch is the number of http sessions. scollector agents are sending puts using a new session each time so it may overload the web server on the receiving end, hence OoMs. Our solution was to lower expiration TTL scollector-initiated sessions.

Comment: How did you lower expiration TTL @SergeiRodionov?

Comment: We have Jetty processing HTTP requests from scollector so we reduced Jetty's default session settings.